# Game updates while playing not working as expected

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I've set up Steam to **stop** downloading updates while I'm playing other games like this:

[image: Global settings]

[image: Game settings]

Anyway Steam doesn't seem to care and keeps updating games while I play.

How can I ensure that Steam is **not** continuing downloads in the background while I am playing games?

Comment: I've had this problem before, it got solved by restarting my PC when changing the settings didn't work. Have you tried rebooting your PC or your Steam client?

Comment: @RegularUser Yes I did both,but still not working

Comment: Is this happening regardless of which game you're playing?  There's both a steam-wide setting and a per-game setting.

Comment: @Powerlord Yes it happens with every game even though my settings for all games are like in the picture

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice there was a link to a picture.  Incidentally, it's possible to attach a picture directly to your question.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is the game you are running a Steam game or added as non-steam game? If it's not either of these, Steam won't be able to say you are playing something, hence it won't stop downloading.

Comment: @Asunez it's a Steam game(Dota 2 in the example)

Comment: Looks to me like you've done everything correctly and Steam is just being buggy

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest limiting your auto-update schedule to some time when you never use Steam, like when you're asleep or at work. That way, it shouldn't start updates while you're playing, and you should still be able to start them manually if you want to.